# Can Xcode 6 GM & Xcode 5.1.1 coexist? (I know the beta could but this app name is the same)

Tags: xcode, xcode5, xcode6

I tried to specify in the title so people didn't think i was a dullard, I've used every version of Xcode 6 Beta alongside Xcode 5.1.1, but as I have only one dev machine I don't want to install Xcode 6 if it will overwrite Xcode 5 entirely.

I also realize I can download/reinstall Xcode 5 but I'm swamped at work and can't afford 30 minutes of downtime even, thanks for the help all!

Comment: You can rename Xcode 5 in applications before you install xcode 6 GM

Comment: They still both exist in the applications folder by doing this however trying to run a simulator in Xcode 5 results in a simulator warning, this is probably because of command line/non-installed iOS7 simulators in Xcode6, I'll test and report back.

Comment: Indeed, after downloading 7.1 simulators in Xcode 6, Xcode 5.1.1 works again in regards to 3.5 & 4 inch iPhones.

Comment: Would using xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app to point to xcode 5 work even if you didn't download the simulators on xcode 6? (Using simulators from different versions of xcode hasn't always been a faithful recreation of what would happen on a real device for me in the past)

Comment: Potentially, I'm not fully versed on xcode-select. I did notice that before having the 7.1 simulators I only saw the iPhone 6 & 6+, afterwards I gained the 4s,5,5s. I plan on only using Xcode 6 for new projects and submitted an update on an old app from it I just like to know the option is there should I come across bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Foolishly I let App Store update Xcode 5.1 and it upgraded me to 6.

1. Renamed /Applications/Xcode to Xcode 6
2. Downloaded Xcode 5.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%205
3. Installed Xcode 5 from the DMG into /Applications
4. Start Xcode 5, rebuild my project and ran my app on my iOS 6.1 device OK.
5. Downloaded iOS6.1 Simulator (Prefences>Downloads)
6. Ran my app in the iOS6.1 Simulator OK.
7. Started Xcode 6, rebuild my project for my iOS6.1 device - reported signing error.
8. In Xcode 6, rebuild my project for iPhone 4s 7.1 - could not boot simulator

Conclusion:
I got Xcode 5 back doing what I needed but will need to do more work to play with Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

So that people don't need to read comments to find the accepted answer:

Yes, MANY versions of Xcode can exist at the same time, in order to prevent overwriting find Xcode in the Finder (CMD+Clicking is one quick method) and rename (simply hit the return key while the app is highlighted) as you see fit. On my machine I have Xcode 5.1.1, Xcode 6.1 and usually whatever Beta Apple has available if I'm having any issues with an app.